# How do asynchronous tasks say they're "done" if there's one thread?

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures, ioloop

I've written asynchronous programs using Tornado and asyncio, however I've realized I don't understand how asynchronous tasks say they're done.

For example, let's take a look at the asynchronous fetch in http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html#examples.

My understanding thus far is:

1. The handler is suspended when `fetch` yields a `Future`.
2. The `Future` is added to the `IOLoop` via http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_future
3. The `Future` finishes, and the `IOLoop` schedules the coroutine to be reanimated so it can complete.

What I don't understand is how the `Future` in step 3 "finishes" and invokes its [done callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future.add_done_callback). I thought there was only one thread, so how would the `Future` "work in the background" and get control so it could invoke the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IOLoop opens a socket to the remote server you're fetching from, and adds that socket to a list of file descriptors on which it's waiting for IO using [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) or a similar system call.

Whenever the loop is not executing your code -- for example, when your handler is paused by `yield`, the loop is waiting for IO, here:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/ioloop.py#L862

When it receives an IO event -- for example, when the remote server sends some response bytes -- Tornado finds the callback that was waiting for that event and executes it.

For an example implementation of an event loop, see [A Web Crawler With asyncio Coroutines](http://aosabook.org/en/500L/a-web-crawler-with-asyncio-coroutines.html).